# AWS EC2 Private Subnet - Host X is not allowed to connect to this Mysql server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a EC2 Box running in a private subnet.  I installed mysql56-server as per: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html (I did not install anything else just mysql).

I also have a development website running in a public subnet.

My issue seems to be that I can not connect to this private instance running mysql.  Error 1130.

For now, on the private instance(running mysql) I opened up all ports and all ips. (just for testing)

Is there anyway to allow my internal ip connect to this server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not 100% clear from the documents, and I am not sure if there is any **serious security implications** from doing this.

First you need to create a new root@someipaddress.  You can use % as a wild card.

As for me ... I just did the following per my setup:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'11.0.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'11.0.1.%';
```

Howevever, I am on a private subnet, that doesnt not allow any direct connections (only from a development server that is public facing, and that is SGed to only me).

Answer (score -1):

One is on a private subnet vs. the other on a public subnet.  You can’t connect the two without a port forward from a private to the public and vice-a-versa.  If you can’t ping one from the other, it won’t work.  Need a load balancer with port forwarding or another machine on the public to forward to the private, like Apache forwarding.

Comment: Stated by question.  I have a development site in a public subnet.  Unless you add the private subnet and network connection to the same private subnet as the EC2 box, no network connection is possible.  Add a network connection to that EC2 private subnet or  add a public subnet to access from the public development box.

Comment: Sorry.  Was trying to keep the answer simple.  If you can make it simple without going into security group configurations and sharing security groups among EC2 instances, perhaps you can explain further.  The simple answer I usually use for making connections between EC2 instances is to put them on the same subnet.  This does not eliminate the need for a public facing netwrok connection for the user to connect to from their own machine.  You need that public facing network for and RDP or Shell session.  Saying that’s not how AWS VPCs work is not helpful.  Better to say just read the AWS docs.

Comment: Really?  monitors for this board?  Just a thought.  Last comment I will make on this as I was attempting to answer a simple question with a simple answer.  Security groups can determine who and what IP, among other things, will have access to the EC2 instance.  I use these to create, for example, a single RDP session capability for ports to a single IP.  This allows that user ONLY to RDP to the instance, provided it has a public IP.  If there is no such IP, good luck with the connection.   This is way beyond the original question I was responding too.   Reading the AMAZON docs may be helpful.